# Include tags and categories in AJAX search results in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, search, categories

We have a search field on our website that uses AJAX. It's purpose is to let visitors search for specific posts, it works great but, the search seems to only search through the title and contents of the posts, we would like it to also search through categories and tags.

Below you can see our code in functions.php. It only searches through titles ans and contents of posts but not their categories or tags

```
 ==================
 Ajax Search
======================   
*/
// add the ajax fetch js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>
<?php
}

// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 8, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => array('post') ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

...
```

Some of our posts have the tag 'male' or 'female' and the title might also contain the words male of female. When a visitor searches the word male it should show the posts with the word male in the tag and/or the title ect. But as I said it only searches through titles and and contents of posts but not their categories or tags, so...

We think our problem might be solved by adding/changing something in this area of the code, but we are not sure what or where exactly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

We have searched the internet for the answer to our problem however, the answers we find are either not related or the solution relies on a plugin, and we would like to fix this thought code and not installing more plugins.

We appreciate any help we can get.

**A SOLUTION WAS FOUND:**
We originally did not want to install any additional plugins to solve this problem however, because we did not find a satisfactory solution we resorted to trying the WP Extended Search plugin. And it works!

Comment: _"We think our problem might be solved by adding/changing something in this area of the code"_ - no, that is completely on the wrong end of the problem. You need to modify the actual database query you are performing, via the `WP_Query` in your `data_fetch` function. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters

Comment: But unless the search keyword is identical with your tag _slug_, it won't be that easy. You might need to "translate" the entered search term(s) into tag IDs first, if that is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but we have already had a look at the documentation you liked. We need our visitors to be able to search through our posts >100 categories and tags, and it looks like this documentation only allows you to put in one at the time?

Comment: There are examples right there ... `Display posts that have “either” of these tags:
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'bread,baking' ) );`

Comment: Thanks but still not very helpful. We don't really want to have to write out >200 tags and categories in a query, and have to change the query everytime a tag or category is added. It doesn't seem very intuitive, there has to be a better way...

Comment: Who said you had to write them by hand, WP has methods to get all tags or categories.

Comment: How good it would actually still perform, if you sticked 200+ tags into such a query, would be a different question. If it is not good enough in that regard, this might be a point at which writing a custom SQL query yourself might make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A SOLUTION WAS FOUND:**
We originally did not want to install any additional plugins to solve this problem however, because we did not find a satisfactory solution we resorted to trying the WP Extended Search plugin. And it works!